# discord.py discord.Message inside function and not as parameter

Tags: python, discord.py

New to coding and not very familiar with the terminology. Currently what I have setup is a user has to input the message ID into the command in order to edit it but I would like for it to be the same message ID every time because of that the user shouldn't need to enter it within the command. When I try to assign the message ID inside the function however I run into a takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given ERROR.

This works: when user does !editembed msgID test test

```
@bot.command()
async def editembed(ctx, message: discord.Message, vols, *, title):
    embed = message.embeds[0]
    embed.add_field(name=title, value=vols, inline=False)
    await message.edit(embed=embed)
```

What I want is something like this: !editembed test test

```
@bot.command()
async def editembed(ctx, vols, *, title):
    message = discord.Message(msgID)
    embed = message.embeds[0]
    embed.add_field(name=title, value=vols, inline=False)
    await message.edit(embed=embed)
```

msgID being the id for the message that is getting updated

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add

```
channel = bot.get_channel(channelID)
message = await channel.fetch_message(msgID)
```

```
@bot.command()
async def editembed(ctx, vols, *, title):
    channel = bot.get_channel(903012463283417138)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(903091631618674688)
    embed = message.embeds[0]
    embed.add_field(name=title, value=vols, inline=False)
    await message.edit(embed=embed)
```